# Trouble getting multiple jquery more/less text expanders working on the same page

Tags: jquery

### Problem:

This function works great when there's one expander on the page - if there's no overflowed text, the more link is hidden.

But if there's more than one expander, it doesn't seem to evaluate each expander separately - so if there's an expander on the page that doesn't have overflowed text, the more link still shows:

```
function textExpander() {
    var expander = $('.expander')
        expanderContracted = expander.find('.expander-contracted');

    // Check if there's overflowed text
    if( (expanderContracted.prop('offsetHeight') < expanderContracted.prop('scrollHeight')) || (expanderContracted.prop('offsetWidth') < expanderContracted.prop('scrollWidth'))) {
        expander.find('a.expander-expand-link[href="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.expand = !this.expand;
            $(this).html(this.expand ? "Less <i class='fa fa-caret-up'></i>" : "More <i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i>");
            $(this).closest('.expander').find('.expander-contracted, .expander-expanded').toggleClass('expander-contracted expander-expanded');
        });
    }
    else {
        // hide more link if there's no overflowed text
        expander.find('a.expander-expand-link').hide();
    }
}
```

---

### Working example:

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cmscss/3xbvxcav/3/

The last one in the fiddle doesn't contain overflowed text but the more link still shows.

---

### Question:

How would I refactor the function so each more link is evaluated on a case-by-case bases?

e.g. show a more link if there's overflown text, hide it if there's isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to verify if text overflows for each `expander` div. Use `each` to traverse each `expander`. After that, get his `expander-contracted` child node. Your condition to check if text overflows is failing because of the `margin-bottom` of the `p` tag. You need to add the margin to the height comparison.

So, instead of

```
if( (expanderContracted.prop('offsetHeight') < expanderContracted.prop('scrollHeight')) || (expanderContracted.prop('offsetWidth') < expanderContracted.prop('scrollWidth')))
```

Should be (in this case, because `margin-bottom` is 10)

```
if( (expanderContracted.prop('offsetHeight') + 10 < expanderContracted.prop('scrollHeight')) || (expanderContracted.prop('offsetWidth') < expanderContracted.prop('scrollWidth')))
```

So, the updated code

```
$('.expander').each(function(){

    var expanderContracted = $(this).children('div.expander-contracted').first();

    if( (expanderContracted.prop('offsetHeight')+ 10 < expanderContracted.prop('scrollHeight')) || (expanderContracted.prop('offsetWidth') < expanderContracted.prop('scrollWidth'))) {
    $(this).find('a.expander-expand-link[href="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.expand = !this.expand;
        $(this).html(this.expand?"Less <i class='fa fa-caret-up'></i>":"More <i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i>");
        $(this).closest('.expander').find('.expander-contracted, .expander-expanded').toggleClass('expander-contracted expander-expanded');
    });
}
else {
    $(this).find('a.expander-expand-link').hide(); // remove more link
}

});
```

If you assume that every `p` tag in has the same value for `margin-bottom`, then you can get the value like this, instead of using the fixed value in the `if` condition:

```
var margin-bottom-p = parseInt($('p').first().css('margin-bottom'));
```

[**WORKING FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3xbvxcav/6/)

Comment: I second this. I have the same thing here http://jsfiddle.net/3leven11/wrk5c9ct/1/

Comment: @HugoSousa Sorry, I left out the function in my fiddle - I need this as a function because I'm calling it when AJAX content loads but am having trouble understanding how I do that with ```.each()```

Comment: @CMSCSS Not sure if I understand. You can place all that code inside a function. Is there a problem with it?

Comment: @HugoSousa That's what I tried - but when called via ajax, any expanders that don't have overflow are still showing their more links (the ones with overflow work great). I just wrapped it like this: ```function textExpander() { ...your code... }``` so might have done that wrong?

Comment: @CMSCSS I would do the same. Is the data in the expanders being set dynamically?

Comment: @HugoSousa - Ajax is loading an entire page of content which contains some expanders so each individual expander is not being loaded dynamically (if that's what you meant?). There's a ```complete``` function within the Ajax call (which also removes a spinner) - that's where I'm calling this function. Hope that all makes sense.

Comment: @CMSCSS My guess would be that if you're loading the expanders in the AJAX call, the size isn't correctly recognized. Try to check the height and width variables and see if they make sense. Otherwise, I'd suggest you to ask a new question with your problem.

Comment: @HugoSousa Thanks heaps - will do! Cheers